# Проблемы с сервером баз данных MySQL (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused)

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

Активно используем бд на чтение и запись, сервер баз данных MySQL, выполняется процесс импорта и других работ.
Проблема заключается в том, что частенько вылетает ошибка `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` при разных запросах select, update, insert и тд. Заметил ошибку в последнее время когда размер бд стал больше чем выделенная в конфиге ОЗУ под нее.
Конфиг mysql

```
[client]
port                        = 3306
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice                        = 0

[mysqld]
user                        = mysql
pid-file                    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port                        = 3306
basedir                     = /usr
datadir                     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                      = /tmp
secure-file-priv            = NULL

skip-external-locking

max_allowed_packet          = 100M
key_buffer_size             = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 4096M
innodb_file_per_table       = 1
innodb_flush_method         = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
max_connections             = 160

long_query_time             = 1

#expire_logs_days            = 1
max_binlog_size             = 100M
disable_log_bin

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet          = 16M
```

Одним из решений наверное было бы увеличить объем ОЗу, но бесконечно же увеличивать его не получится т.к. бд постоянно растет. Есть какие-то другие варианты решения этой проблемы?

Последние логи за сегодня конейнера mysql

```
2020-12-26 00:43:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26 00:43:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-12-26 00:43:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26T00:43:18.244214Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-12-26T00:43:18.256839Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-12-26T00:43:21.418998Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-12-26T00:43:21.621634Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-12-26T00:43:21.720132Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-12-26T00:43:21.723062Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-12-26T00:43:21.754033Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-12-26 01:00:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26 01:00:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-12-26 01:00:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26T01:00:11.889893Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-12-26T01:00:11.904031Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-12-26T01:00:14.374501Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-12-26T01:00:14.722195Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-12-26T01:00:14.786147Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-12-26T01:00:14.789253Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-12-26T01:00:14.822480Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-12-26T06:39:15.054863Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-12-26 06:40:27+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26 06:40:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-12-26 06:40:28+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26T06:40:28.954425Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-12-26T06:40:28.987416Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-12-26T06:40:33.545273Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-12-26T06:40:33.843566Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-12-26T06:40:34.007675Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-12-26T06:40:34.012998Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-12-26T06:40:34.068772Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-12-26T06:55:32.406940Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-12-26 06:55:34+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26 06:55:34+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-12-26 06:55:34+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26T06:55:35.479370Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-12-26T06:55:35.496525Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-12-26T06:55:37.154719Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-12-26T06:55:37.433835Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-12-26T06:55:37.593885Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-12-26T06:55:37.596152Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-12-26T06:55:37.621147Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-12-26 08:43:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26 08:43:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-12-26 08:43:41+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26T08:43:42.364663Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-12-26T08:43:42.383092Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-12-26T08:43:45.650870Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-12-26T08:43:45.826187Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-12-26T08:43:45.894372Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-12-26T08:43:45.897032Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-12-26T08:43:45.923281Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-12-26T08:46:14.992253Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 11  user: 'app'.
2020-12-26T08:46:16.655425Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-12-26 08:46:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26 08:46:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-12-26 08:46:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26T08:46:21.417657Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-12-26T08:46:21.434561Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-12-26T08:46:22.918554Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-12-26T08:46:23.109405Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-12-26T08:46:23.225924Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-12-26T08:46:23.229630Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-12-26T08:46:23.269575Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
2020-12-26 09:06:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26 09:06:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-12-26 09:06:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
2020-12-26T09:06:32.815176Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
2020-12-26T09:06:32.833090Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-12-26T09:06:35.035344Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2020-12-26T09:06:35.202616Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-12-26T09:06:35.283163Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-12-26T09:06:35.285898Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-12-26T09:06:35.325343Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mbind: Operation not permitted
mysql> show status like "%onn%";
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name                                         | Value               |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Aborted_connects                                      | 11                  |
| Connection_errors_accept                              | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_internal                            | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_max_connections                     | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_peer_address                        | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_select                              | 0                   |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap                             | 0                   |
| Connections                                           | 276                 |
| Locked_connects                                       | 0                   |
| Max_used_connections                                  | 5                   |
| Max_used_connections_time                             | 2020-12-26 09:45:02 |
| Mysqlx_connection_accept_errors                       | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connection_errors                              | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connections_accepted                           | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connections_closed                             | 0                   |
| Mysqlx_connections_rejected                           | 0                   |
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_longest_seen | 113                 |
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost         | 0                   |
| Ssl_client_connects                                   | 0                   |
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates                              | 0                   |
| Ssl_finished_connects                                 | 0                   |
| Threads_connected                                     | 4                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
22 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Смотреть логи mysql и выявлять причины ошибок

Comment: в логах ошибок нет, добавил логи к вопросу

Comment: @Pavel - А причём тут память?! Ошибка "Connection refused" - это когда к серверу пытается подключиться кто-то, у кого нет на это соответствующих прав. Смотрите таблицы, управляемые командами grant: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html

А в логах смотрите, кому **конкретно** было отказано в доступе.